# what should be the auto return url for paypal civicrm?

Tags: civimember, paypal

I am setting up membership renewal using a contribution page and payment processor is Paypal Standard, what should be the Auto Return URl which should be incorporated in paypal website payment preference so that it redirects to thank you page of contribution?

Currently, it does not redirect automatically (probably due to it being in sandbox),when I do click on button Return to Website , it takes to Thank You Page and shows message "You don't have access permission to view the page"

Comment: Have a look at the docs for setting up civicrm and PayPal, and update your question with details if that doesn't work? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/paypal-standard/

Comment: Can you include CMS and CiviCRM version in your question?

Comment: I've never configured an Auto Return URI - and it seems like it wouldn't wok to have a single URI because I might use PayPal Standard on multiple contribution pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Return URI should be the URL of your site. The [docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/paypal-standard/#then-set-the-auto-return-so-the-contributor-goes-back-to-your-site) says

> Enter your CiviCRM site home page as the Return URL. This is a placeholder. CiviContribute will pass the exact return URL to PayPal automatically during each transaction.